# "Стык в стык" в качестве "пунктуально"

Tags: фразеология, семантика

Может ли фразеологизм "стык в стык" указывать на пунктуальность человека, на своевременность его появления?

Он явился на занятие стык в стык с преподавателем.

Comment: Хорошо было бы почитать примеры в НКРЯ. (http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=paper&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&req=%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BA+%D0%B2+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Стык в стык* - встык, плотно прилегая, соприкасаясь.

*Таким же образом приклеивайте каждый последующий кусок. Его можно наклеивать либо стык в стык, либо с небольшим нахлестом.*

К. А. Ляхова, Спальня

*Девяносто полотен было развешано в круглом зале на одном уровне, почти стык в стык.*

Афанасий Полушкин, Йестердэй, 2013

*Огромные камни, из которых построена стена, слишком гладкие и лежат друг с другом стык в стык.*

Джей Би Рем, Сингулярность

*Второе полотнище приклеивается либо стык в стык, либо в небольшой нахлест.*

Л. Ж. Жалпанова, Гостиная

В вашем случае это "**тютелька в тютельку**".